# convert php regex to android java regex

Tags: java, php, android, regex

Can somebody help me with converting a PHP regex to Java format?

It would be great and I would appreciate if anyone could help me, because I'm not so strong in regex.

This is a PHP code:

```
$string = file_get_contents('a.txt');
$regex = '/\b(http|https):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
$urls = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Hire a freelancer or do it yourself, trial and error is the way to go.

Comment: Should be pretty much the same regex I believe just replace ``\`` with ``\\`` in java

Comment: I believe more needs to be changed, a lot need to be escaped. But the `\b` and `/i` I'm not sure how to implement...

Comment: I said I was not sure. I know most of the changes will have to do with escaping. The rest I did not try: if it works, then great! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should double escape the *back*slashes and you do not have to escape `/`s:

```
String rx = "(?i)\\b(http|rtmp|rtsp|mmsh|mms)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]";
```

Sample code to get all matches (do not forget about including `import java.util.regex.*;`):

```
String str = "http://google.com";

String rx = "(?i)\\b(http|rtmp|rtsp|mmsh|mms)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yous saved my day,I integrated it directly and works very well.Now i have time today to continue work.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Basic Regex syntax are same in all language Just be careful around the escape character things. 
To escape special characters use `\\`, there is no need to escape `/`

and some parameter will be given in a different way in java like.

use `(?i)` at the beginning  instead of `/i` at the end

boundary expression `\b` also same in java but you will need to add `\\b` in java because `\b` will be considered as a backspace  back-space character

Your pattern will look like:

`(?i)\\b(http|rtmp|rtsp|mmsh|mms)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]`